# VBA showing something as false, that's true

Tags: vba, number-formatting

I'm trying to determine the CellFormat of a given cell. When I use Immediate to check, the following is 'False':

```
 Range("E250").NumberFormat = "_([$€-2] * #,##0.00_);_([$€-2] * (#,##0.00);_([$€-2] * " - "??_);_(@_)"
```

Yet when I run the following in Immediate,

```
 ?Range("E250").NumberFormat
```

it gives me the value it's set equal to above (meaning the 1st one should be True). I've tried setting it equal to a variable, and still persisted. Been going in circles on this. This seems simple, but I'm not sure why it's not showing true.

Comment: The embedded double quotes make the whole thing essentially "`string1` minus `string2`". However you should be getting a type mismatch error.

Comment: @GSerg How can I still check for this Accounting type (€-based specifically) then?

Comment: Use double ```""``` instead of one ```"``` inside of the number format string where the ```minus``` character is placed. Like this ```...-2] * ""-""??_);...```